# What is the list of requirements of this laravel questions

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel, You can say totally beginner.

Now, I got this question:

https://hackmd.io/@DVDk95AlS3CX53FGzfJXZA/r1bWEs3CH

Can someone tell me what is the **list** of requirement'**s** of this question? How can I solve it?

**wait**

I am not asking the actual code, just tell me the resources and list of tasks list.

***Your help would be much more appreciated.***

Comment: It's a list of endpoints that define an API to interact with a key-value store (e.g. it could be a wrapper to a redis server). Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @apokryfos is that question is asking that I need to create 2 column database table for key and value? or I need to add 3 column for key, value and TTL? If so then what is the way to implement the TTL?

Comment: The Laravel Docs should have you covered most of the way (I'm assuming you're not new to web development as well). Since you're starting with Laravel and the description is pretty specific about using a RESTful approach and a persistent store, you might want to start with [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests) and [Response](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/responses) docs as well as the [Database](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database) part of the docs for persistence.

Comment: @Bogdan wait, I am giving you Laravel code which I did so far

Comment: @Bogdan check this link please. Am I doing right ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86b0b3680eff5332170b51adc10ad4f82630af7f and http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d143f0496ece1102c9d8dedf41d40daf46f8690e

Comment: [Laravel's cache](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/cache) already supports a TTL you don't need to implement one yourself. I don't think there's a requirement to implement this from scratch

Comment: @apokryfos I want to know the list of requirements of that link questions clearly. Can you help me?

Comment: The requirement is : *Create an API with the following endpoints to create a key-value store. The purpose of the API is to store any arbitrary length value in a persistent store with respect to a key and later fetch these values by keys. These values will have a TTL (for example 5 minutes) and after the TTL is over, the values will be removed from the store.* which parts of this are you do you have difficulties understanding?

Comment: I mean is it asking to create 3 columns for the MySQL table for key, value and TTL field for each record?

Comment: It's not asking you to make a specific implementation. It's asking you to make an API. How you choose to implement the back-end is your own personal choice. Personally I'd go for Laravel's cache backed by a Redis store, but that's only because I'm familiar with how to use that. You should choose what you're most comfortable with implementing

Comment: BIG thanks to you and one last question. how can I implement TTL? with Cache features of Laravel?

Comment: If you use `Cache::put(key, value, $ttl)` this will store a value for `$ttl` seconds. The caveat is that if you use a database or file to back the cache the expired values are not actually removed when they expire but are just ignored. In that case you may need to do a manual database sweep of expired values every now and then. If you use Redis this is not usually necessary

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Routing in order to create all the routes you need that can communicate with your controllers : [Routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing) and [Controllers documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers).

For the JSON responses, you can use this method: [Json Response documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#json-responses) .

For access to the incoming Http parameters you can use these methods: 
[Http requests parameters documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. now is that question is asking that I need to create 2 column database table for the key and value?

Comment: To communicate with database you can use models: [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent). You have to create a Model class for every table, set the name of the table with `protected $table = "YOUR TABLE NAME"; ` and set the communication with database as shown in this documentation [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/database)

Comment: No, I know how to create table but I want to know that the link question is asking me to create 2/3 column mysql table to store key, value and TTL?

Comment: For the TTL you can use the fields `created_at` (a DateTime field) that is set by default by Laravel models and you can create a command that deletes rows that are older than 5 minutes. Is this a possible solution?

Comment: I want that command to run automatically as the questions asked, right? Shall I need the help of Cache? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

Comment: I think not. You can create a simple command that returns all the rows older than 5 minutes and delete them. Cache is not necessary.

Comment: Rember to mark my answer as acceptable if it helps you! :)